# Can we return a custom object type from a .JWS file

Tags: java, web-services, axis

Here is my situation:
I'm using Apache Axis 1.1. I'm trying to set up a custom web service as  a .jws file that is simply dropped onto the axis web app folder. So I'll have `/axis/MyWebService.jws`

This all works well and good, the WSDL file is automatically generated etc. However, I want to be able to return more than just `String` of `Integer` etc. I want to be able to return simple Java Bean type objects as well.

Given that I'm stuck to the technology that I'm using, is there any way for me to accomplish this? My tomcat environment is `java 1.5.XX`, but it looks like the `.jws` files are *compiled* using 1.4 or so, b/c they cannot contain Generics etc.

I'm open to suggestions, as long as I don't have to overhaul the structure, or change the environment etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it;s just a matter of having a Java Bean type class put into the class path accessible by the JWS file. Once it's there, the automatic conversion to XML takes care of creating a Complex SOAP type etc... so Easy as pie, just need to have your code in the right place! Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Oh No? Well in my case, I wrote a simple Java class and then dropped the class file into an appropriate location visible to the jws file. It was picked up and the WSDL for the webservice showed the object as a soap type, so that any client could build the object as needed in any language.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance Mr Drinker :) I'm sure I could nut it out if given enough time. Turns out it's easy enough to leave that functionality out of my project, and time pressures have kept pressing so I'm going to deliver the first iteration without a query function.